# Angular 7 payment success URL return HTTP 405 Error

Tags: angular, payu

I am using `payU` payment gateway. This is my payment URL:

https://localhost:4200/#/mobile/en/payment?token=*****&orderId=1002

My success url is:

https://localhost:4200/#/mobile/en/success?token=*****&orderId=1002

But `payU` return this url:

https://localhost:4200/?ctrl=9ed57312bfac920b82922b75e90093d0#/mobile/en/success?token=*****&orderId=100

`payU` add ?ctrl=9ed57312bfac920b82922b75e90093d0 due to these I got HTTP 405 status code.

Please help me how can I resolve this issue?